# Cannot redeclare class in PHP error

Tags: php, require

new to PHP. Using the SLIM framework and the routing has been tested and is working fine. Have two files index.php and API.php. index.php is:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'API.php';

//Turn on error checking
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

//Create a new SLIM app
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');


$app->get('/', function() use($app) { 
    $app->response->setStatus(200);
    echo "InstaAPI\n";
});

$app->run();

?>
```

API is:

```
<?php

class DbHandler{

    protected static $conn;

    function __construct() {

        //Static self notation is different
        if(!isset(self::$conn)) {
            //same as self.connect
            $this->connect();
        }

    }

    function __destruct(){

        if(isset(self::$conn)){

            self::$conn->close();
        }

    }


    function connect(){

        $config = parse_ini_file('../../config2.ini');

        // Try and connect to the database
        self::$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);

        if(self::$conn===FALSE) {

            header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
            header("Content-Type: application/json");
            $response = array("Response"=>"Failed to connect to the database");
            echo json_encode($response);
            die();

        }

        else{

            echo "Fine!!";
        }

    }//end connect


}//end class


?>
```

I am getting the error: `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class DbHandler in ../API.php on line 62`. Not sure why this is happening. I am using `require_once` and still getting the same error. Could someone give me some pointers to what I might be doing wrong please?

Comment: require 'vendor/autoload.php'; would normally load many required classes. Is your API already declared inside of those classes?

Comment: My guess is that `DbHandler` is already declared  in one of the modules loaded by `autoload.php` , try changing the class name to something else.

Comment: autoload.php is associated to the SLIM framework so DbHandler won't be declared in there

Comment: There seems to be a second `API.php` in `../` as per the error?

Comment: "_on line 62_"? Are you sure that you didn't copy and paste the same class in `API.php`?

Comment: that's odd if I change the name of the class i.e to DBBHandler it works...why would that be happening?

Comment: @MrLister just corrected that. Still won't let me call the class DbHandler tho...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code of Api.php is less than 62 lines. looks like there is extra code below it. consider deleting extra lines